# Angularjs multiple fields in single field set

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

if i have a schema like this .. 
how can be my view page input fields ...

```js
name:{ type:String}
personnel:{
    sales: { type:String},
    account: { type:String}
}
```

Not able to insert or get data trying like this from the view page..

```html
<!--to insert-->
name:<input type="text" ng-model="clients.name">
personal:    
Sales:<input type="text" ng-model="clients.Personnel.salesExec">
account:<input type="text" ng-model="clients.Personnel.account">

<!--to retrive-->
<tr ng-repeat="clients in clientsList">
    <td>{{clients.name}}</td>
    <td>{{clients.personnel.sales}}</td>
    <td>{{clients.personnel.account}}</td>
</tr>
```

In my controller i have:

```js
var clientsApp = angular.module('clientOn');

clientsApp.controller('controllerMain', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

        console.log("controller invoked");

  //acts as get all data
  var refresh = function() {
    $http.get('/clients').success(function(response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested");
        $scope.clientsList = response;
        $scope.clients = "";
        });
  };
  refresh();


//add data
$scope.addclients = function(){
    console.log($scope.clients);
    $http.post('/clients',$scope.clients).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        refresh();
    });
};
      })
```

*do help.. thanks in advance*

Comment: Don't use Angularjs and switch for like ANY real MVVM framework and you'll be fine

Comment: show your code for controller as well

Answer (score 1):

## two-way-data-binding

This code snippet from the Angular JS website shows input and output with 2 way data binding

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
    Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
  </form>
  <pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>
  <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();
  }]);
</script>
```

With a working example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) on the angular js website.

## Mongoose

If you want to use schema with JSON like data (BSON is what mongodb actually uses) you should use the express package mongoose. [Here](http://mongoosejs.com/) is a link to the awesome docs, very helpful and thorough.

But for this you will need to set up a full stack (MEAN stack) to put things in the database and retrieve them.

## Firebase

Alternatively you could use something like fire base. [Here](https://www.firebase.com/) is a link. All you have to do then is create a factory that makes a http call to firebase to get the data you require.

Then set that data to a `$scope` in your controller and add it to your html view.

If you have little to no backend exp this is the fastest way to set up imo.

Best of luck.

Comment: You have a schema and then skip to the controller and view. Are you useing mongoose and mongodb? You have no service/factory to get or post. You dont show your backend routes. Do you have a full stack or just views and a "schema"? Link github repo of the project if you have one.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654142/how-should-i-create-controller-and-view-page-in-angularjs-with-group-values-mong) plz look at this....

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing code with this code:

```
<!--to insert-->
name:<input type="text" ng-model="clients.name">
personal:    
Sales:<input type="text" ng-model="clients.Personnel.salesExec">
account:<input type="text" ng-model="clients.Personnel.account">

<!--to retrive-->
<tr ng-repeat="clients in clientsList">
    <td>{{clients.name}}</td>
    <td>{{clients.Personnel.salesExec}}</td>
    <td>{{clients.Personnel.account}}</td>
</tr>
```

There is difference of lowercase and uppercase in your code. Also for sales, you are using `clients.Personnel.salesExec`while getting data but using `clients.personnel.sales` while displaying data,which is incorrect.
It should be the same variable. Hope this will help you.